# Convergence of the sequence $a_n := 1+\frac{1}{2}$+$\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

assume valid the folling inequalty:

$\frac{1}{n+1}<ln(n+1)-ln(n)<\frac{1}{n}$

Show that then the sequence {an} n∈N
It is decreasing and that each an ≥ 0
which concluded that the sequence is convergent.

Comment: Missing information is present. Are you after a proof that the Euler constant exists?

Comment: sorry I'm new with MathJax and it is difficult to me to edit

Comment: No problem; got you covered. Is your question in the present form the question you are asking?

Comment: yes, I do not see how to deal with it

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  Decreasing:
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\ln n+\frac1{n+1}-\ln(n+1)$$
and now use the first inequality you are given.

Non-negative: using the second inequality,
$$\eqalign{a_n
  &>(\ln2-\ln1)+(\ln3-\ln2)+\cdots+(\ln(n+1)-\ln n)-\ln n\cr
  &=\ln(n+1)-\ln n\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 2):

Upon observing that
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n} - \log n = (1 - \int_{t=1}^{2}\frac{1}{t}) + \cdots + (\frac{1}{n-1} - \int_{t=n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{t}) + \frac{1}{n}
$$ 
for all $n \geq 1$,
that
$(\frac{1}{k})$ is decreasing and $\to 0$,
and that $\int_{t=k}^{k+1}\frac{1}{t} < \frac{1}{k}$ for all $k \geq 1$ by assumption, it follows that $(a_{n})$ is decreasing and $\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. Calculate $a_{n+1} - a_n$ to prove that $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing.
2. Consider the sequence $b_n = 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1n - \ln(n+1) = a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}$. Calculate $b_{n+1} - b_n$ to prove that $\{b_n\}$ is increasing so that $a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} = b_n > b_{1} > 0$.